# Preventing default button behavior (page reload) in react button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if I'm asking a question that's been answered before. I did my due diligence but maybe I'm not understanding correctly. I'm currently trying to make my buttons in a react app not reload the page, just refresh the state.

Main file/App.js:

```
<Button
    onClick={() => this.callAPI('api')}
    type="success"
    className="input-lg">
    Search
</Button>
```

Button Component:

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ type = "default", className, children, onClick }) {

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={["btn btn-lg", `btn-${type}`, 
    className].join(" ")}>
    {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

I've tried changing the button type, and I've tried making a new function then adding it to the onClick:

```
componentDefault = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ type = "default", className, children, onClick }) {

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick} className={["btn btn-lg", `btn-${type}`, 
    className].join(" ")}>
    {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;



<Button
    onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault();this.callAPI('api');}}
    type="success"
    className="input-lg">
    Search
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to sure on how your code is actually structured but I would do something like this

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
   }
   onClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Do something
   }
   render() {
     return (
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Button Text</button>
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it inside a `Form` if so, it becomes a `submit` button.

I suggest a slight change of you code:

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ type, style = "default", className, children, onClick }) {

  return (
    <button type={type} onClick={onClick} className={["btn btn-lg", `btn-${style}`, 
    className].join(" ")}>
    {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Try to pass it the `button` type:

```
<Button type="button">Reload</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your `onClick`:

```
onClick={(e) => { this.callAPI('api'); e.preventDefault() }}
```